# I need to update two fields; one is dependent on the other

Tags: multiple-columns, updates

Here is what I want to work, but I don't know that the sequence of actions will make it work correctly:

UPDATE table SET field1 = field1 + 1,field2 = field3 * field1

After adding 1 to field1, use this new value to relace field2 with the calculation field3 * field1

It looks good but I don't know if (1) the first update will be the "first" update, and (2) whether the calculation in the second update will pick up the new, incremented field1 value.

I suppose another option would be:

UPDATE table SET field1 = field1 + 1,field2 = field3 * ( field1 + 1 )

But this assumes that field1 is NOT updated before the calculation in the second update is made.

IDEAS?????

Comment: What happens when you try it in your test environment? Also keep in mind that an update without a where clause will update every row.

Comment: Got it about the WHERE.  I just didn't show it in the example.

My concern with the UPDATE is that I don't know if there is any guaranteed execution sequence for the field updates. Also, whether the updated field1 will carry into the second field update.  If there is no rule as to the execution sequence I am concerned that one version of MYSQL will work as I want, and then the next version acts differently.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/105368/update-query-field-order-guaranteed

Comment: Thanks much for your fast response and good advice.